# Improve Tesseract Accuracy on my book images, for Google Books API

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, google-books-api

I am trying to upload my library to goodreads, so I am taking a picture to get the details of each book and then I use Google books api to get the isbn number.

Unfortunately, pytesseract is not detecting the text properly.

Here is one image:
[image]

The result after thresholding:

[image: thresh]

and here is my code:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2
import pandas as pd


#We then read the image with text
img=cv2.imread(image_path)
original = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
# threshold the image, setting all foreground pixels to
# 255 and all background pixels to 0
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
text = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh, lang='eng',  output_type='data.frame')
```

but the results are far from great.
I have tried to deskew the images and process them differently but the results are not better.

Is there a way to improve the image processing or another library method I should try that might work better?

Comment: if you're using the google books API already, may I suggest that you use further google APIs to recognize the book cover entirely, from just the picture

Comment: OpenCV is powerless if Tesseract simply refuses to work right. Tesseract simply isn't state of the art. there will be no end to the "custom filtering" you'd have to perform ***differently*** for every artfully designed book cover. just give up there and use something ***other than*** Tesseract.

Comment: Any API you have in mind? Reverse image search was my next thought , is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: reverse image search API only delivers "similar images". you might wanna look at the google lens API. google lens web page, given your image as a query, gives me a "book bubble" right at the top, so it must be aware that it's a book, and which book.

Comment: Fabulous, thanks! Will give it a try :)

Comment: I looked and there is no google lens api. I will try to scrape the search results.